# Problema Paste VB NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

Buenas tengo un problema con fecha y números al pegar del portapapeles a Excel. He intentado usar el pasteSpecial, usar una plantilla con formatos preestablecidos.. pero sigue dejando los datos como tipo texto. ¿Alguna recomendación?

```
    Dim xLibro As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim RutaExcel As String
    RutaExcel = "RAIZ.xls"
    xLibro = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xLibro.Workbooks.Open(RutaExcel)
    xLibro.Visible = False
    xLibro.Workbooks("RAIZ.xlsx").Activate() 
    xLibro.Sheets("datos").Select()
    xLibro.Range("A2").Select()
    xLibro.ActiveSheet.paste
    xLibro.Sheets("DETALLE").Select()
    xLibro.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(“TablaDinámica2”).PivotCache.Refresh
    xLibro.DisplayAlerts = False
    xLibro.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(RutaExcel)
    xLibro.Quit()
    Me.Close()
```

[image: FORMATO WK1]

Comment: Creo que no estás implementando bien el uso de la función, que te parece si echas un ojo a la documentación https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.paste

Comment: @Ivan-San He mirado otros códigos y ejemplos, lo usan de este modo, mi problema es con el hecho del pegado, lo pega bien pero como texto pierde el formato de date y number (no los coge como tal). Gracias

Comment: Has intentado darle formato a la celda? 

range.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";